# opencv 2.4.3 configuration issue with visual studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, opencv

I have tried to install and configure opencv and link it with visual studio 2010 in 32bit windows 7 but after all the configuration when i debug a piece of code i get this error really need help please help.

"error LNK1181: cannot open file 'opencv_calib3d243d.lib'"

"'opencv_calib3d243d.lib'" was included during the configuration, but still i get this error.

I have followed the coniguration procedure from here.

[Installing OpenCV 2.4.3 in Visual C++ 2010 Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10901905/installing-opencv-2-4-3-in-visual-c-2010-express)

Comment: Make sure you configure the right path for libraries in your project properties.

Comment: Are you sure you compiled the library for VS2010?

Answer (score 0):

There might be 2 things that are the source of your woes:

1. You are trying to link to x64 instead of x86 (this is assuming that your OS is 32-bit, of course)
2. You haven't specified the Linker Directory properly.

I would advise you to use [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake_tutorial.html) to link your libraries as it will make your life a lot simpler.. Please refer to my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19678321/opencv2-4-6-cuda5-0-vs2010-in-debug-mode-dont-display-images/19679286#19679286) for details..