# Linking error with OpenCV on OS/X

Tags: macos, opencv, linker, linker-errors

When I try to build an OpenCV application:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (argc < 2) {
        cout << "usage: " << argv[0] << " image.png" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    Mat im = imread(argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

I get a linker error:

```
bash-3.2$ g++ `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` fs.cpp
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "cv::imread(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, int)", referenced from:
      _main in fs-EK7vjB.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Here are the libraries I'm linking against (OpenCV installed via homebrew):

```
bash-3.2$ pkg-config --libs opencv
/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.5/lib/libopencv_calib3d.dylib /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.5/lib/libopencv_contrib.dylib /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.5/lib/libopencv_core.dylib /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.5/lib/libopencv_features2d.dylib /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.5/lib/libopencv_flann.dylib /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.5/lib/libopencv_gpu.dylib /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.5/lib/libopencv_highgui.dylib /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.5/lib/libopencv_imgproc.dylib /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.5/lib/libopencv_legacy.dylib /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.5/lib/libopencv_ml.dylib /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.5/lib/libopencv_nonfree.dylib /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.5/lib/libopencv_objdetect.dylib /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.5/lib/libopencv_ocl.dylib /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.5/lib/libopencv_photo.dylib /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.5/lib/libopencv_stitching.dylib /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.5/lib/libopencv_superres.dylib /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.5/lib/libopencv_ts.dylib /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.5/lib/libopencv_video.dylib /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.5/lib/libopencv_videostab.dylib
```

Slightly more readable list:

```
bash-3.2$ for f in $(pkg-config --libs opencv); do echo $(basename $f); done
libopencv_calib3d.dylib
libopencv_contrib.dylib
libopencv_core.dylib
libopencv_features2d.dylib
libopencv_flann.dylib
libopencv_gpu.dylib
libopencv_highgui.dylib
libopencv_imgproc.dylib
libopencv_legacy.dylib
libopencv_ml.dylib
libopencv_nonfree.dylib
libopencv_objdetect.dylib
libopencv_ocl.dylib
libopencv_photo.dylib
libopencv_stitching.dylib
libopencv_superres.dylib
libopencv_ts.dylib
libopencv_video.dylib
libopencv_videostab.dylib
```

What am I doing wrong, and how can I make things work?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are not linking the right libs for your system. Try CMake to create your project files (please refer to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19678321/opencv2-4-6-cuda5-0-vs2010-in-debug-mode-dont-display-images/19679286#19679286) for details).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. These are the only libs I have. If they're not the right libs, then what good will CMake do? How can I check if these are indeed the right libs or not?

Comment: Building the sources is a nice way to make sure. Kudos.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the homebrew install of OpenCV is broken. I built the library from source and it worked.

1. Download and unpack the most recent tarball from http://opencv.org/
2. mkdir opencv-2.4.7/build
3. cd opencv-2.4.7/build
4. ccmake - set all the relevant options, in particular CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX
5. make
6. make install
7. export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/Users/misha/lib/pkgconfig (or wherever you've installed the library)
8. pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv - confirm that pkgconfig picks up your newly installed libraries
9. build the application

Also, you may want to remove the broken homebrew opencv:

```
brew uninstall opencv
```